# When would $DLN_LIBRARY_PATH be useful?

Tags: ruby, windows, bash, posix, environment-variables

I understand that it's a place to store a "[Search path for dynamically loaded modules](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/rubyworld.html)," but I would be grateful if someone could please provide an example use case for **$DLN_LIBRARY_PATH** with Ruby.

Comment: There is no $DLN_LIBRARY_PATH.  Are you perhaps talking about $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?  That's not generally used for ruby modules/libraries.

Comment: If you click on the link in my question, you'll see that the table titled "Environment variables used by Ruby" includes the following row: "`DLN_LIBRARY_PATH` Search path for dynamically loaded modules."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ruby cannot be linked against user C extensions in advance, it loads them at runtime as shared libraries. These extensions have to be loaded from somewhere, and that's exactly what `DLN_LIBRARY_PATH` specifies: the list of directories where shared objects or DLLs may be found.

It is similar to the [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html), which provides the same information for the dynamic linker on Unix-like systems.